# Shutdown computer automatically after set bandwidth is used

Tags: windows-10, internet, shutdown, automation

On my internet pack that I now have, I get a set amount of data free for use at midnight. What I would like to do is to automatically shutdown my computer after the set amount of data is used, whether or not a download is in progress.

I would appreciate any help with this question.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:- I do not wish for my connection to be active. I want my computer to shut down, as clearly stated. I am looking for a purely software solution. My ISP has data caps and I don't want to get charged extra. My ISP does not do this for me. I use W10x64, purely personal connection.

Note:- I am basically looking for a program (portable or not) for personal use (with or without a GUI) that is straightforward enough, like those programs that automatically shutdown your computer when internet usage goes below 10KBps etc...

Thanks for all the help I've received.

Comment: That seems a bit drastic: why not disable the internet connection? This would best be done by controlling router settings, so that your intranet remains active. For an answer, we need to know a lot more: OS? Router model? How do you monitor data use? You should also investigate whether your internet provider will do this for you.

Comment: @Sanoo: what operating system are you using?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter-Poulsen Windows 10 Pro x64